# Apache Ignite: Getting the current nodeId

Tags: curl, ignite

I have an Apache Ignite cluster running with 4 nodes on Kubernetes. I want to make sure that the node are alive for the liveness probe. Basically, if a node is no responding I need to remove it from the cluster.
I am looking on getting the nodeId of the Apache Ignite using the curl command. On a Apache Ignite pod, I can run `curl "http://localhost:8080/ignite?cmd=version"`

Is there a curl command using the REST API to get the current nodeId? I looked at the documentation, but I could not find anything
https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/restapi

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get `nodeId` by using the `node` command and providing the node's IP address:

```
http://host:port/ignite?cmd=node&ip={nodeIp}
```

More information related to this endpoint can be found [here](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/restapi#node).

Regarding the detection and removal of unresponsive nodes from the cluster, Apache Ignite does that automatically using the [discovery mechanism](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/clustering/clustering#discovery-mechanisms). You can find additional details about that in the `Detecting and Removing Failed Nodes from Topology` section [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/IGNITE/TCP+Discovery+SPI+under+the+hood).

Comment: A better way to do it would be `http://host:port/ignite?cmd=node&ip=$(hostname -I)`